# How do I tell my GNUMakefile to link against a specific library?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep, gnu-make

My GNUMakefile is as follows:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

APP_NAME = MyApp

MyApp_HEADER_FILES = src/objc/framework/Bug.h src/objc/framework/NSMutableArray+Shuffle.h src/objc/framework/World.h src/objc/framework/BugProtocol.h src/objc/domain/RandomBug.h 
MyApp_OBJC_FILES =  src/objc/framework/Bug.m src/objc/framework/World.m src/objc/framework/NSMutableArray+Shuffle.m src/objc/domain/RandomBug.m 

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/application.make
```

In my code I'm using `arc4random`, which means that I need to link against `libbsd`. How do I do that in my makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. I used `ADDITIONAL_TOOL_LIBS`:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

APP_NAME = BhumiApp

BhumiApp_HEADER_FILES = src/objc/framework/Bug.h src/objc/framework/NSMutableArray+Shuffle.h src/objc/framework/World.h src/objc/framework/BugProtocol.h src/objc/domain/RandomBug.h 
BhumiApp_OBJC_FILES =  src/objc/framework/Bug.m src/objc/framework/World.m src/objc/framework/NSMutableArray+Shuffle.m src/objc/domain/RandomBug.m 
ADDITIONAL_TOOL_LIBS = -l:libbsd.so.0

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/application.make
```

Comment: without some familiarity with the GNUstep makefiles, there's no way anyone could have guessed this.

Comment: It wasn't easy to figure this out... I eventually found a page that listed the different variables that a GNU Makefile uses.